# Monomorphism between abelian groups and quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Could someone help me with the following question?

Let be $A,B$ two abelian groups and $f:A\rightarrow{B}$ a monomorphism between them. What should we understand when we write the quotient group $A/B$? (we don't know if $B$ is a subgroup of $A$)

Thanks.

Comment: It's usually $B/A$ (as the monomorphism may just as well be interpreted as an inclusion). I have no idea what one would make of $A/B$ generally.

Comment: Yes, I also think like you. But I have found it in a excercise

Comment: Can you give a link to this exercise?

Comment: I can give you the statement of the exercise:  If $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2$ are abelian group and $f_i:A_i\rightarrow{B_i}$ with $i=1,2$ are monomorphism, prove that $(A_1\oplus{A_2})/(B_1\oplus{B_2})$ is isomorphic to $(A_1/B_1)\oplus{(A_2/B_2)}$

Comment: I'd be willing to bet the author reversed $A$ and $B$ accidentally.